# HBase Master: CodedInputStream encountered an embedded string or message which claimed to have negative size

Tags: hbase

- HBase 1.5
- Hadoop 2.9.2

Getting this error when trying to access HBase web ui:

```
2020-03-11 13:43:55,295 ERROR org.mortbay.log: /master-status
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: com.google.protobuf.InvalidProtocolBufferException: CodedInputStream encountered an embedded string or message which claimed to have negative size.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Solution

1. Stop hbase `master`, `backup-master`, and `region servers`
2. Run offline repair of hbase master table using `hbase` command:

   ```
   hbase org.apache.hadoop.hbase.util.hbck.OfflineMetaRepair`
   ```
3. Login to Zookeeper and delete hbase root directory:

   ```
   deleteall /hbase
   ```

   note: *you may need to recreate the directory and set zookeeper permissions correctly again via* `setAcl`
4. start HBase `master`, `backup-master` and `region server`